# Why does my GSAP slider animations stop working after I tried to animate my Nav bar

Tags: javascript, gsap

```
//Animation on slider
const tl = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { ease: "power1.out" } })

tl.to(".text", { y: "0%", duration: 1 });
tl.to(".slider", { y: "-100%", duration: 1.5, delay: 0.5 });
tl.to(".intro", { y: "-100%", duration: 1 }, "-=1");
tl.fromTo("nav", { opacity: 0 }, { opacity: 1, duration: 0.5 });
tl.fromTo(".shortDescription", { opacity: 0 }, { opacity: 1, duration: 0.5 });
tl.fromTo("footer", { opacity: 0 }, { opacity: 1, duration: 0.5 });

/*Animation on the Nav Bar
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.selection');
const bubble = document.querySelector('.bubble');
const gradient = ["linear-gradient(to top, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%)"
    "linear-gradient(to top, #a8edea 0%, #fed6e3 100%)"
];

const options = {
    threshold: 0.7
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(navCheck, options);

function navCheck(entries) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        console.log(entry);
    });
};

section.forEach(section => {
    observe.observe(section);
});*/
```

This is the whole javascript code that I have, I currently put the nav bar animation to a comment for the gsap slider to work. but when I'm already trying to input the nav bar animation the gsap code stops working so the whole set would be stuck with the color black and it won't slide through, so you won't see the  page itself.

Comment: can you put this into a codepen/jsfiddle?

Comment: https://codepen.io/kyle-ballerda/pen/PozWMEw @littletinyman